# Make own graphical server

Tags: linux, tty, framebuffer

I had experience to work with framebuffer and found it pretty well to make own graphical applications. But the problem is that framebuffer is too slow.

My goal:
1) Make a new `tty` which will work for framebuffer only 
2) Avoid framebuffer on other TTYs
3) Provide fast read-write for /dev/fb
*4) Use GPU for framebuffer operations

Comment: Have you looked into `wayland`? A lot of the people currently involved with X11 are very frustrated with it.

Comment: I'd like to avoid any kind of APIs, I need something low level.

Comment: Wayland replaces X11 completely, it would be about as low level as you'd really want to go.

Comment: In my question I've asked about **framebuffer-like interface**, Wayland just doesn't give me it.

Answer (score 1):

Try [DirectFB](http://www.directfb.org/). It handles figuring out which operations can be accelerated in hardware for your display device.

Comment: It looks pretty nice, but not solution of my current problem. I need something like: couple of commands -> and my framebuffer becomes into separated TTY, couple of code -> I have acceleration.